# Check/radio box disappear when using -webkit-perspective in Safari

Tags: css, webkit, safari, css-transforms

Here's a quick demo, Safari only. http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/8AJnD/
If you remove the perspective style, all checkboxes appear normal. Using `-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d` does the same thing (i.e. checkboxes disappear). Seems to apply to radio boxes as well but not input elements.

Most likely this is a bug in Safari but I just wanted to confirm that there are no solutions to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a bug in safari. Chrosme does not even support it yet.
here is an example that works in safari: http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/perspective-by-example.html

This means that it is really the inputs that break the page. try to submit the bug to apple :)

Here is the same page with 2 inputs added to it: http://jsfiddle.net/8AJnD/17/

as you see they do not show.